# How can my Shiny App in shinyapps.io load local data?

Tags: r, shiny

I want my shiny app to load the data from the user computer, for security reasons. I don't want to upload the data, I want to send the user the file, and when he opens the app on shinyapps.io, it will load the data from his computer (A .csv located inside C:/, for example).

An ideal solution would be to the user to chose the file from his computer, but any of these will help a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just one file, you can try using the `read.csv(file.choose())` function inside the global.R file if that works with you application requirement.

If there are multiple files that you want to load, I guess using the `fileInput` is a better option. You can get some help with using it here:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/upload-file.html

https://gist.github.com/psychemedia/9737637

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks! I'll try out asap

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are looking for the `shiny` function `fileInput` which allows a user to upload one (or several) files that you can then handle (generally within a `reactive` function) and pass to your other outputs.